# How do I make a randomly sized image element square and also responsive(% width and not pixels)?

Tags: html, css, image

How do I make a randomly sized image element square and also responsive?

Comment: You should elaborate your question. What do you mean by "responsive"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
element.style.height = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101) + "%";
element.style.width = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101) + "%";
```

Math.floor() returns the largest integer less than or equal to a given number

Math.random() returns an number between 0 and 1.

Note that we're using JavaScript because HTML/CSS can't make random number.

From https://css-tricks.com/generate-a-random-number/